# The remained global flavor symmetries of massless quarks after gauging electromagnetic $U(1)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

For $N_f$ numebr of massless quarks, we know that there are global symmetries
$$
\frac{SU(N_f)_L \times SU(N_f)_R \times U(1)_V}{Z_{N_f}}
$$
here $U(1)_V$ is the same as $U(1)$-Baryon number conservation. The axial $U(1)_A$ is anomalous.

> Question: What would be the remained global flavor symmetries of massless quarks after gauging electromagnetic $U(1)_e$? We can take $Nf=3$ where we have 3 quarks like $u,d,s$.

[WARNING]: Notice that $U(1)_e$ is part of the vector global flavor symmetry $SU(N_f)_V$, and gauging result in the remained $SU(N_f-1)_V$ global flavor symmetry. Namely, $U(1)_e$ is part of $SU(N_f)_L \times SU(N_f)_R$. However, we note that
$$SU(N_f)_L \times SU(N_f)_R \neq SU(N_f)_V \times SU(N_f)_A$$
because the left-right chiral flavor generators DO commute, but the vector and axial generators of $SU(N_f)_V$ and $SU(N_f)_A$ do NOT commute. So the answer won't be as simple as
$$
\frac{SU(N_f-1)_V \times SU(N_f)_A \times U(1)_V}{Z_{N_f}} [\text{This is WRONG!}]
$$

What is your answer?

Comment: The axial generators do *not* close into an SU(2)_A, so that group is non-existent. Look at your current algebra.

Comment: Thanks, I know you cannot write $SU(n)_V  \times SU(m)_A$ as a group. So I am asking how to write the global symmetry group.

Comment: *u* and *d* have different charges, so cannot be in a single rep of $U(1)_e$.

Comment: The  $U(1)$ is diagonal, but the element in $N_f=3$, you can consider a Lie algebra generator matrix proportional to $diag(2/3,-1/3,-1/3)$. It is still a $U(1)$, but not the complex $U(1)$ as $+e^{i \theta} \mathbb{I}$. I am talking about the different $U(1)$. The $SU(N)$ has no $e^{i \theta} \mathbb{I}$., only $U(N)$ has $+e^{i \theta} \mathbb{I}$ But it is already taken care carefully in my question. [What you said is not part of my question.] Thanks

Comment: I am talking about the  $U(1)_e$ diagonal for  $N_f=3$, you can consider a Lie algebra generator matrix proportional to $diag(2/3,-1/3,-1/3)$.